# Where to download iTunes 11 for Windows?

Tags: itunes, windows

I'm trying to rescue family photos from an old iPod 1st gen (A1213). This thing has never seen a software update, it doesn't even have Appstore. Unfortunately Apple dropped support for this device in iTunes 12, therefore I wasn't able to connect it to iTunes or set it up as a USB storage device, both on MacOS and Windows.

**My only hope is to install iTunes 11 on a Windows machine** - mainly from this [video tutorial](https://youtu.be/RA_uV_QOEk0)

It's 2022 and [Apple doesn't supply version 11 for windows anymore](https://support.apple.com/downloads/itunes). Sites like `oldversion.com.de` and `ihackintosh.com` don't seem to exist anymore. I couldn't even find a torrent for it. Does anyone know of another source for old Windows iTunes versions?

Comment: Try [iExplorer](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer) to see if you can access the device. It comes in macOS and Windows flavors and doesn't need iTunes.

Comment: A1213 is an iPod **Touch** 1st gen [2007]. Big difference, the 1st gen iPod didn't even have USB, it was Firewire ;) I can mount & update an iPod 'Photo' from 2004 that can still be managed by iTunes 12 [but on Mac]. BTW, on Mac you never used iTunes to get photos **off** them, only to put them on. iPhotos/Photos or Image Capture are to get them *from* the device. [I'm trying to find mine to test… not used it in a long while…]

Comment: Found it - gimme a min to see if I can squeeze a bit of charge into it...

Comment: The iPod had just started up - interestingly DropBox is offering to back it all up [which I shall decline]… The iPod has some photos. iTunes [of course] will not offer to import them, the pod is slave not master. Image Capture cannot see it. Conclusion… getting it to mount on iTunes or Image Capture will not help. Windows needs to be able to mount it as a 'volume' which Mac will never do. Maybe iExplorer or iMazing can do it. iMazing has a special version for iPod - https://helpdesk.macroplant.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018856454-My-device-isn-t-appearing-in-iExplorer- Regular ver can't see mine

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you for the ideas! Just tried iExplorer on Macbook and PC and iMazing on PC. They don't recognize the iPod. [iExplorer say](https://helpdesk.macroplant.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018856454-My-device-isn-t-appearing-in-iExplorer-) they rely on iTunes to recognize the device, and iTunes doesn't, even though I installed [v10.5.3](https://en.softonic.com/download/itunes-64-bit/windows/post-download/v/10.5.3). Connecting the iPod on windows makes the USB sound and shows an empty DCIM folder, even though there are ~1400 photos on it. At no point does the iPod ask to trust the computer.

Answer (score 1):

The Internet Archive provides a Windows executable for iTunes Setup 11.4.0.18 (32 Bit): https://archive.org/details/i-tunes-setup-11.4.0.18-32-bit

Direct .exe link: https://archive.org/download/i-tunes-setup-11.4.0.18-32-bit/iTunesSetup%2011.4.0.18%2032-Bit.exe

*Disclaimer: I do not have a Windows installation to verify that this installer works, or is legitimate Apple iTunes.*